# T-PUMP DML ERROR

Tags: teradata

While running T-PUMP  I'm getting DML error. Here is my script that is loading data from a file to a table `infa_source12`:

```
.LOGTABLE  etlt5.EMP_TPUMP_LOG;
.logon ttdbia/USR/PASSWRD;
.BEGIN LOAD;
PACK 5
RATE 10
ERROR TABLE Etlt5.TPUMPERROR;
.LAYOUT RECLAYOUT;
.FIELD    id        * varchar(10);
.FIELD    name      * varchar(20);
.FIELD    country   * varCHAR(30);

.DML label INST;

INSERT INTO etlt5.infa_source12
(id,name,country)
VALUES 
(:id, :name, :country) 
.IMPORT INFINE /home/a0c9sx/SQLAExport.txt;
LAYOUT RECLAYOUT
APPLY INST ;
.END LOAD;
.LOGOFF;
```

```
ERROR:
**** 10:18:50 UTY2832 A .DML statement must be entered before any SQL
```

I referred to the below link:

http://www.teradatawiki.net/2013/10/Teradatautilities-tpump.html

Answer (score 1):

Your script is full of synax errors (copied from that website):

```
.LOGTABLE  etlt5.EMP_TPUMP_LOG;
.logon ttdbia/USR/PASSWRD;
.BEGIN LOAD; -- no semicolon, the next keywords are part of BEGIN LOAD
        -- SESSIONS is missing
 PACK 5
 RATE 10
 ERROR TABLE Etlt5.TPUMPERROR; -- no space between ERROR and TABLE
.LAYOUT RECLAYOUT;
.FIELD    id        * varchar(10);
.FIELD    name      * varchar(20);
.FIELD    country   * varCHAR(30);

.DML label INST; 

INSERT INTO etlt5.infa_source12
(id,name,country)
VALUES 
(:id, :name, :country)  -- missing semicolon, needed for each SQL statement
.IMPORT INFINE /home/a0c9sx/SQLAExport.txt; -- no semicolon, the next keywords are part of IMPORT
LAYOUT RECLAYOUT
APPLY INST ;
.END LOAD;
.LOGOFF;
```

It will save more time when you follow the examples found in the manuals...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing part of the command syntax for the `.DML` command. What isn't clear is whether or not you need to use `SERIALIZEON` or not.

```
.LOGTABLE  etlt5.EMP_TPUMP_LOG;
.logon ttdbia/USR/PASSWRD;
.BEGIN LOAD;
PACK 5
RATE 10
ERROR TABLE Etlt5.TPUMPERROR;
.LAYOUT RECLAYOUT;
.FIELD    id        * varchar(10);
.FIELD    name      * varchar(20);
.FIELD    country   * varCHAR(30);

.DML LABEL INST
  DO INSERT FOR;

INSERT INTO etlt5.infa_source12
(id,name,country)
VALUES 
(:id, :name, :country) 
.IMPORT INFINE /home/a0c9sx/SQLAExport.txt;
LAYOUT RECLAYOUT
APPLY INST ;
.END LOAD;
.LOGOFF;
```

There is more information on the T-Pump command syntax in the Teradata Manuals [here](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_10/Load_and_Unload_Utilities/B035_3021_082K/3021title.html).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Rob :)
I'm new to Teradata ,if I can get some quick help .it will be time saving,this manual Will take too long to understand